# Javascript displays a different image every minute. How can add info from db to images?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, clock

I have a working JavaScript that refreshes a different image every minute, based on the time of the day. The script takes the images from a folder that contains files named after every single minute... eg: 0435.jpg (if 4:35 am).

What I want to do is update the following js to make it able to pull these images from a database, since they were uploaded along other info (name, comment, city) stored in a db... I want the pics to display next to this info.

```
<img id="myImg" class="round" alt="This is the time" src="minute/default.jpg" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function() {
    var myImg = document.getElementById('myImg');
    myImg.src = '/minute/' + new Date().toTimeString().substring(0, 5).replace(':', '') + '.jpg' ;
    onerror = myImg.src = '/minute/default.jpg' ;
  }, 30000);
</script>
```

I don't know how to approach this situation. I am a newbie in JavaScript.

Comment: put the information in a file and grab that as well. e.g `$('#infobox').load('/path/to/server/yourdatetimevaluehere');`

Comment: to get the related info from the db you will need an ajax call to your server to fetch that data. php for example.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to accomplish this but it didn't work for me.

Comment: You have the images files in some folder. Do you also store these images in a database? What kind of database? You state that you have a working JS. So what exactly does not work vs what exactly does work? If you can, isolate what you're trying to achieve in a self-containing reproducible full-detail example, so that we could run and experience the issue.